# How can I create a date field by HTML5 Pattern (DD.MM.YYYY)

Tags: html

I have that code:

```
(?:19|20)[0-9]{2}-(?:(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(?:0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9])|(?:(?!02)(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(?:30))|(?:(?:0[13578]|1[02])-31))
```

Checks that

1) the year is numeric and starts with 19 or 20,

2) the month is numeric and between 01-12, and

3) the day is numeric between 01-29, or

b) 30 if the month value is anything other than 02, or

c) 31 if the month value is one of 01,03,05,07,08,10, or 12

It's from page http://html5pattern.com/Dates

I tried to move some part of code, but then this code doesnt work... Even I tried to find some instructions how can I do it. But I can't handle with it...

How can I get a result like with above code but in format:

DD.MM.YYYY

Also is there any possibility to add the dots in field that user can only input the numbers without dots? 
(I mean that the dots will be there every time)

Thank you for help.

Sorry for my English.

Comment: *a field phone* and *dd-mm-yyyy* don't match. Consider editing your question title so that it matches the question you're asking. This also has nothing to do with *design-patterns*.

Comment: I'm so sorry. There should be "a field date" .

It's my mistake! Is there possibility to correct it?

Comment: There's an [edit] link beneath the tags on your question  You might also want to explain what the format `DD.MM.RRRR` is supposed to represent - what is `RRRR`? (The requirements you're asking about should be done in code, not in the regular expression for the field, BTW. Regexes are for pattern matches, not complex validation logic.)

Comment: Of course it should be YYYY.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is something that you are looking for:

```
(?:(?:0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9])\.(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])|(?:30)\.(?:(?!02)(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2]))|(?:31)\.(?:0[13578]|1[02]))\.(?:19|20)[0-9]{2}
```

Also tried some possible test cases and worked fine:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! This is it. :) It works great!

Where do you have that good things like on the screenshot? :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use an input mask plugin for some of what you are asking for instead I suppose.

One popular one that comes to my mind is Robin Herbots: https://github.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask

You can find demos off his page here: https://robinherbots.github.io/Inputmask/index.html

Once you implement the plugin into your page, then it's just a matter of establishing the right input tags and jquery for them. For example:

Your phone number script would then be something along the lines of:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#Phone").inputmask({mask: "999.999.9999"});
</script>
```

You should look up the documentation for it.